# Google map not displaying in Android- Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I have done all the settings needed for displaying google map.

Everything works fine. When I run the app, Map is not displaying.

Following is my code,

```
package com.example.findproperty;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Logcat,

```
04-23 06:57:23.189: W/ActivityThread(3685): Application com.example.findproperty is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-23 06:57:23.289: I/System.out(3685): Sending WAIT chunk
04-23 06:57:23.309: I/dalvikvm(3685): Debugger is active
04-23 06:57:23.339: I/System.out(3685): Debugger has connected
04-23 06:57:23.360: I/System.out(3685): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 06:57:23.558: I/System.out(3685): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 06:57:25.188: I/System.out(3685): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 06:57:25.388: I/System.out(3685): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 06:57:25.668: I/System.out(3685): debugger has settled (1447)
04-23 06:57:27.108: W/dalvikvm(3685): VFY: unable to resolve static field 873 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
04-23 06:57:27.108: D/dalvikvm(3685): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
04-23 07:14:55.779: I/jdwp(3685): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
04-23 07:19:31.823: E/Trace(6321): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 07:19:31.949: W/ActivityThread(6321): Application com.example.findproperty is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-23 07:19:32.069: I/System.out(6321): Sending WAIT chunk
04-23 07:19:32.089: I/dalvikvm(6321): Debugger is active
04-23 07:19:32.278: I/System.out(6321): Debugger has connected
04-23 07:19:32.278: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:32.503: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:32.709: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:32.909: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:33.109: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:33.325: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:33.528: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:33.728: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:33.948: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:34.148: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:34.448: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:34.648: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:34.850: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:35.048: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:35.258: I/System.out(6321): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:19:35.538: I/System.out(6321): debugger has settled (1440)
04-23 07:19:41.869: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:19:41.929: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:19:41.989: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:19:42.059: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:19:42.119: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:19:42.399: D/dalvikvm(6321): GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 12% free 2591K/2916K, paused 103ms+13ms, total 208ms
04-23 07:19:45.879: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(6321): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:43.240: W/ActivityThread(7607): Application com.example.findproperty is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
04-23 07:30:43.318: I/System.out(7607): Sending WAIT chunk
04-23 07:30:43.339: I/dalvikvm(7607): Debugger is active
04-23 07:30:43.518: I/System.out(7607): Debugger has connected
04-23 07:30:43.528: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:43.728: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:43.938: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:44.138: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:44.348: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:44.548: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:44.748: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:45.040: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:45.238: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:45.440: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:45.640: I/System.out(7607): waiting for debugger to settle...
04-23 07:30:45.848: I/System.out(7607): debugger has settled (1384)
04-23 07:30:47.689: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:47.739: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:47.799: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.   Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:47.939: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:48.009: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-23 07:30:48.359: D/dalvikvm(7607): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 12% free 2583K/2912K, paused 92ms+24ms, total 230ms
04-23 07:31:04.578: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7607): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
```

Manifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.findproperty.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.findproperty.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.findproperty.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Given the key" />
 </application>

</manifest>
```

please help me to come out of this problem!!!

Comment: As the Log mention "Google Play services out of date.", have you update your google play service to newest version on your device?

Comment: but how to update that?? PLease give the idea.

Comment: Emil has anwer the question. If you want to run your program on emulator you can take a look this blog http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2012/12/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this on the emulator, then the Google maps files you pushed to the `AVD` are old and not compatible with the latest version of the `google-play-services` library that you are probably using.

If you running this on a real device then update the `google-play-service` via the `Play Store`.
To update follow this link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Comment: You can't update it in the emulator, you have to find a newer set of the 2 files you installed to the AVD, or down-grade you google-play-services library you are using in your workspace

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse..
In **Window** menu -> click **Android SDK Manager**
After open **Android SDK Manager**, see the last tab **Extra**.
Check the **Google Play Service** option and **Update** it..